# Active a Unity animation if certain conditions are met?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, triggers, game-engine, animator

I'm developing a 2d game in Unity and I ran into a problem. When trying to create animation transitions for one of my animations for some reason Unity instantly or very quickly deactivates my animation(like less then a second after I activated it). However when I don't have a transition conected to the animation the animation works fine. However I need to be able to transition the gameobject back to the state it was in before the animation after a certain condtion is met and so I cant leave the animation running. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Ive tried switching the way I activate the animations to see if it might be related to this by trying both a bool and trigger as the condition that determines when a transition should happen but the same problem arrises

THis is a rough outline of how I activate the animation

```
public class InteractControl : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
{ 
    public static float timeLeft = 10f;

    public void OnObjectSpawn()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Change this method to just be a temporary obstacle
    void Update() 
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            anim.enabled = true;
        }


        if (timeLeft < 0)
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("FollowAd");
        }
    }
}
```

Ad Follow with transition:

[image: Ad Follow with transition]

Ad Follow without transition:

[image]

Transition Settings:

[image]

The animation should activate if `timeLeft` is bigger than `0` and deactivate as soon as it is smaller then `0` and return the the gameobject to the state it was in before the animation started. Right now if Ad Follow_ has no transition the animation works when called upon but doesn't deactivate. if Ad Follow_ has an empty state connected to it to which it should transition should

```
anim.SetTrigger("FollowAd");
```

be called like shown above it works for less then a second or not at all and then switches straight back to the default state. It should only switch back when `timeLeft < 0`.

Comment: Could you show the settings for the transition? Also note that you keep calling `SetTrigger` **every frame** while `timeLeft < 0` .. also during the transition so your trigger isn't reset correctly. You could maybe avoid it using `anim.ResetTrigger("FollowAd");` in `if(timeLeft > 0)`;

Comment: @derHugo I added a printscreen of the transition settings that I have for the animation

Comment: As said I guess the main issue is that you continue firing `anim.ResetTrigger("FollowAd")` try to disable it nad make sure it is only called **once** by a flag like `private bool triggerFollowAd` set it to true when you start the animation `triggerFollowAd = true; anim.enabled = true;` and later check it and also set it to false like `if(time < 0 && triggerFollowAd){ triggerFollowAd = false; anim.SetTrigger("FollowAd"); }`

Comment: @derHugo I created a private int that is set to 1 at its field intialization and then incremnts right after I acces the anim.ResetTrigger but it still doesnt work.       if (triggerFollowAd == 1)
                    {
                        anim.enabled = true;
                        triggerFollowAd++;
                    } the gameobject acts as if there is no animation at all

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public RuntimeAnimatorController animCon` for your required animation. When your conditions are met. You can do `anim.runtimeanimatorcontroller = animCon;`.

And When the condition is false do this `anim.runtimeanimatorcontroller = null;`. Its not the best way but its quick and better then most.

Answer (score 0):

You have `AllFollow` as the default animation to be played.

This means that animation will always play when the animation controller is instantiated.

Also, your transition to `New state` has an `Exit time`. You don’t want that, untick that box if you’re relying on a condition.

And change the new state name to something more informative :)